# Running Decap with C#

Tags: point-clouds, revit-api, autodesk

In the office we have a fileWatcher that converts pointclouds to .laz files.
We just started working with Revit but came to the conclusion that it is not possible to import .laz in Revit.
So I googled and found a solution execept it is written in python and our watcher is in c#.
Below the python script.
`<location>/decap.exe –importWithLicence E:\decap text\Building 1\ Building 1`
Is there a way to convert this python script to c# or is there maybe another way.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Jeremy. After some more searching I came to the same conclusion. Below you will find the code that worked for me.

```
//Process Info
var cmdInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,

    UseShellExecute = false,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
};

//Process
var cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo = cmdInfo;
cmd.Start();

var outStream = cmd.StandardOutput;
var inStream = cmd.StandardInput;

//Command Line for DeCap
inStream.WriteLine("cd C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk Recap");
var run = true;
var cmdTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (run)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(outstream.ReadLine());
        }
        catch { }
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        if (outStream.ReadLine().Contains("[R]"))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(@"File Converted: {0}\{1}", _LAZProcessed, LAZFile.Name);
            run = false;
        }
    }
});

inStream.WriteLine("{0}decap.exe{0} --importWithLicense {0}{1} 0} {0}{2}{0} {0}{3}{0}", '"', _LAZProcessed, LAZFile.Name, LAZFile.FullName);

while (!cmdTask.IsCompleted)
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Revit add-in in C# to [import a LandXML surface](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/import-landxml-surface.html) to a `TopographySurface`. The `LAS` file format is just as simple and readable as LandXML, so that ought to give you what you need. I am interested in implementing such a thing for myself as well, in fact, so maybe if you can share a simple `LAZ` sample file or two I can take a look at it as well. Thank you.

I see that `decap.exe` is an Autodesk product, and has nothing to do with Python. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Just generate the topography surface, or something else besides that?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, what i am trying to achieve is a point cloud in Revit. Our office works with a lot of pointclouds and I have written a script which makes a Revit document for every point cloud in a specific folder. The only problem now is that we can't import `LAZ` into Revit. With the python script mentioned a `LAZ` file can be converted to `RCS`. And then it could be imported into Revit. To summarize I am trying to convert a `LAZ` file to `RCS` so I can import it into Revit.

Comment: My question is: what is the *exact* result in Revit? What elements are generated, what properties do they have, what data is added? If it is one single `TopoSurface` element with no additional data, it is simple and I can understand. Everything beyond that I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer asked what you are trying to achieve and addressed a possible alternative approach. To answer your question more directly, you can easily launch the `decap.exe` command line and specify arguments to it directly in .NET and C#. Simply make use of the command line as explained elsewhere, e.g., to [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).